# SQL join help for friend list

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three database tables: `users`, `user_profiles` and `friends`:

**users**

- id
- username
- password

**user_profiles**

- id
- user_id
- full_name

**friends**

- id
- usera_id
- userb_id

What would be a query which finds the friends list of any user and also joins the table `users` and `user_profiles` to get the profile and user information of that friend?

Comment: You don't need the 'id' column in the friends table - you just need a unique constraint on the combination of 'usera_id' and 'userb_id'.

Comment: Making `usera_id` and `userb_id` the primary key (a composite/compound) would be ideal.

Comment: It also isn't clear what the 'id' column in user_profiles would be used for.  If a single person (as identified by id number in the users table) was allowed to have several user_profile entries, and if there was a way to identify which of those several user_profile entries was to be used at any given time, then maybe the user_profiles.id column would be of some relevance.

Comment: a check constraint where usera_id < userb_id helps eliminate "dups" like bob+joe and joe+bob

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, @OMG Ponies, @KM -- You're making the assumption that a "friends link" is reciprocal. Just because Bob is friends with Joe, does not necessarily mean Joe is friends with Bob. It depends on the designed behavior of the application. Maybe Joe unfriended Bob, but the requirement of the application is to not let Bob know that he has been unfriended, so the Bob->Joe friend association still exists but not the Joe->Bob situation.

Comment: @Adam Porad: how do you interpret that from my answer?  The 'a' and 'b' roles ('befriender' and 'befriended' or vice versa) are identified separately.  There is nothing in my answer that assumes that if 'a' befriends 'b' then 'b' also befriends 'a'.  Filters for identifying 'people befriended by user XYZ' or 'people who have befriended user XYZ' are easily applied.

Comment: Hello previously I tried to make a relationship table friends in such a way that if both usera and user b are friends it creates entry to the table friends. while it seemed difficult to map the relation ship that way. So i just made double entry to the friends table when the friend request is accepted. so if user a and userb are friend. two entries one for friend of usera and one for friend of userb is Inserted to the friends table.
IS it correct way to do thisor is there any other way aswell?
thanks

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler yeah. you're totally right. I guess I picked a bad day to quit drinking coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT f.username,
       up.*
  FROM USERS f
  JOIN USER_PROFILES up ON up.user_id = f.id
  JOIN FRIENDS fr ON fr.userb_id = f.id
  JOIN USERS u ON u.id = fr.usera_id
 WHERE u.username = ?
```

...assuming `userb_id` is the friend id.

Comment: The friends ID can be in any field usera_id or userb_id. When both are friends the data is inserted in the friends table. So friend id can be in both a or b

Comment: @askkirati: That I understand, but if you are wanting the friend list of a given `USERS` record you have to pick one of the two directions.

Comment: ponies: How do i decide the direction. Because if userb first adds the user a the userb's id will go to usera_id field and usera in userb_id field. How do i find the direction.Or should i create two entries in the friends table

Comment: This worked correctly thanks i needed to make two entry for friend list

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but this felt like the logical way:

```
select a.id , a.friend_id ,
Users.username
from
 ( SELECT id , IF(usera_id = 1, userb_id , usera_id) friend_id
 FROM friends
 where usera_id = 1 OR userb_id = 1 ) a
left join Users on a.friend_id = Users.id
```

this uses a mySQL function so probably wont work in Oracle/MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Falling back on bad habits (not using JOIN notation in the FROM clause):

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, a.full_name,
       b.id, b.username, b.full_name
  FROM friends AS f, users AS ua, users AS ub,
       user_profiles AS a, user_profiles AS b
 WHERE f.usera_id = ua.id
   AND f.userb_id = ub.id
   AND a.user_id  = ua.id
   AND b.user_id  = ub.id
```

The key point is using table aliases (all those 'AS' clauses) and referencing the same table more than once when necessary.

Someone could write this with JOIN instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some modification to [eugene y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203513/sql-join-help-for-friend-list/2203595#2203595), will this work?

```
SELECT * FROM users u
JOIN friends f ON (f.userb_id = u.id OR f.usera_id = u.id)
JOIN user_profiles p ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Comment: It seems to work now can i select only specific fields of the joined tables user_profiles