# Displaying friends from a friend list

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am building a community website where I have put the functionality of adding people as friends.

Now my friends table looks like this

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | ppl_1   | ppl_2 | 
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |    5    |  7    | 
|  2 |    13   |  5    |
+----+---------+-------+

id is simply the autoincrement field.
ppl_1 is one user's id
ppl_2 is another user's id
```

Now consider I am the user whose id is 5. I want to see my friend list. How am I able to work that out because my id can be anywhere either between `ppl_1` or `ppl_2`. So do I have to run 2 queries to check? That will be bad I guess considering the performance of the site.. Or do I have to do something within one single query to check both ways?

Considering `$me = $_SESSION['id'] ;`

Anyone show me some light here?

Comment: Using a `UNION` you can do 2 queries in one, where the 1st selects the friends in `ppl_1` and the second the friends in `ppl_2`, ie. `SELECT ppl_1 as friend ... UNION ... SELECT ppl_2 as friend ...`

Comment: this problem has been addressed many times. [sql-join-help-for-friend-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203513/sql-join-help-for-friend-list) [how-to-represent-symmetric-many-to-many-relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550093/how-to-represent-symmetric-many-to-many-relationship) [how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship)

Answer (score 0):

It would help you if you rename the columns ppl_1 and ppl_2 in your table to better reflect their actual meaning.

You could name them something like 'friend' and 'befriended_by'

Then you would execute a join:

```
SELECT befriended_by 
FROM user
INNER JOIN [name of your table above]
ON user.id = friend
WHERE user.id = [:id, please use parameterised queries to insert your $_SESSION['id'] here or some other sane method to prevent sql injection attacks ]
```

That's it.

Comment: What if in one row `befriended_by` contains my id and in another row 'friend' contains my id? As I have mentioned already. My id can be in any one of the columns all along the way to the bottom of the table. I don't want to select my id and to select the other person's id.

Comment: Hi Sagnik, that's ok. Each column has a different function; if you want to get a list of your friends you are interested in the values in the column `friends` for the rows where `befriended_by` is your id. If you want to know who added you to their friends list you are interested in the values in the column `befriended_by` where `friends` is your id. Check the question pointed out by abl, it might help you clarify the concept.